# Merging Records in CSV Using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am working in c# and my programming skills are rusty to say the least. File1.csv has column headers and a primary key. File2.txt is delimited with a ; and does not have headers. Both sheets hold information about items, with a SKU and a Price. Basically, if the SKU exists on File1.csv, then update the price on File2.csv to math, otherwise leave it alone. Both of file1 is about 10MB and file2 is 50MB+. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Not much, I have them both loaded to dataTables, but that is about it.

Comment: I found [this](http://udevi-community.blogspot.com/2010/04/code4food-5-how-to-join-multiple-csv.html) searching Google.